PHP inheritance in constructor
I'm doing tests.
Given this code snippet
<?php

class Point
{
    public $x;
    public $y;

    public function __construct($x, $y) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }
}

class Point3D extends Point
{
    public $z;

    public function __construct($x, $y, $z) {
        $this->z = $z;
    }
}

$p = new Point3D(1, 2, 3);
echo sprintf('(%d, %d, %d)', $p->x, $p->y, $p->z);

I'm confused because the correct answer seems to be :

(0,0,3)

But $x and $y are not initialized in child class.
__parent() is not called
When I run the code in a sandbox, it does give the expected answer
When I ask ChatGPT about it, he gives the answer I would have given : $x, $y are not initialized before... => fatal error
The question is why both me and ChatGPT are wrong
What's the principle here ?

Add parent::__construct($x,$y); to the constructor.

Your problem has to do with typed properties. When you aren't using typed properties like in your example, then PHP will do its best to work with what it's given.
Using your same example, we can use type-hinting to enforce our expectations, but without calling upon the parent
Sandbox code here
<?php
class Point
{
    public int $x;
    public int $y;

    public function __construct(int $x, int $y) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }
}

class Point3D extends Point
{
    public int $z;

    public function __construct(int $x, int $y, int $z) {
        $this->z = $z;
    }
}

$p = new Point3D(1, 2, 3);
echo sprintf('(%d, %d, %d)', $p->x, $p->y, $p->z);

Output:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property Point::$x must not be accessed before initialization in /home/user/scripts/code.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 23

Note that the above fatal error is pointing out the typed property. By using strongly-typed code, PHP will enforce those checks and throw errors when it encounters a scenario in which the provided type cannot be determined.
Note also that unless you use declare(strict_types=1);, even if you pass a string or other non-integer value in this case, PHP will allow those values to pass through and do some type-juggling automatically.
That said, once we include our parent constructor everything will run without issue:
class Point3D extends Point
{
    public int $z;

    public function __construct(int $x, int $y, int $z) {
        parent::__construct($x, $y);
        $this->z = $z;
    }
}

Additional Details:
Part of why your original example "works" as well is that you're still telling PHP a little about your expectations through the use of sprintf. You're seeing (0, 0, 3) in your output due to the fact that you have uninitialized variables with no type, but you're still telling PHP that these are expected to be digits.
So because you aren't declaring typed properties in your original example, but later telling PHP that we want digits as part of our output, then it will default those values to 0.
Had you used - say - (%s, %s, %s) as your format, your output would have been (, , 3).
This is why arguments are made for strong-typing, because in any application of reasonable complexity, you want to ensure that that values you're working with at any point in time are what you're expecting. Passing in bad information and allowing it through without errors can actually result in problems and bugs and future headaches because of the system not throwing an error at the point in time when a bad value might have been passed in.
